# mounting several apps with camping

Tags: ruby, web-applications, camping

I'm testing how to mount several apps in camping, and I am following [these instructions](https://github.com/camping/camping/wiki/Rules-of-Thumb). I have this structure:

more/apps/

```
pm.rb
qm.rb
```

Both apps just return the index view with some text. When I startup the server, the index shows the pm's index when the address is `http://localhost:3301/`.

If I try `http://localhost:3301/pm`, I get this error:

```
Camping Problem!

/pm not found
```

Same error for qm. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work anymore. `camping` now only accepts a single file. You can still mount multiple apps, but you need a single file that requires them:

```
# in apps.rb
require 'pm'
require 'qm'
```

And then you can run:

```
camping apps.rb
```

Comment: Hi Magnus,thank you for the reply, but I can't make it work. I've made a gist [link](https://gist.github.com/sebastjan-hribar/039748f06964f3fa9589) with files and error trace. The error shows what happens after I try accessing /qm. It states it can't load the pm file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this yet but in the issues on camping github they mentioned using a config.ru like you would for any Rack app.
I hope this helps.